# redirecting a php url with 2 parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to set up my api to have 2 endpoints, and the simplest way I have seen to do this is to have a .htaccess file that would redirect something like [www.website.com/api/category/platform](http://www.website.com/api/category/platform) to display the same as [www.website.com/api/index.php?category=platform](http://www.website.com/api/index.php?category=platform) . The issue I am now running into is that I want it to include a second parameter such as [www.website.com/api/index.php?category=platform&filter=price](http://www.website.com/api/index.php?category=platform&filter=price) to be the same as [www.website.com/api/category/platform/price](http://www.website.com/api/category/platform/price) or even [www.website.com/api/platform/price](http://www.website.com/api/platform/price)

The current .htaccess file is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?category/([^/d]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I would rather recommend using the [Front Controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) and a router. You basically pass all requests to index.php, where you have defined routes (url patterns) in your code. The router then matches the URL and call the configured callback for that route. It makes it much easier to add new routes with different url structures. It also makes it easier to move your app between web servers (like to nginx that doesn't use htaccess files).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson While this would probably be a better option for me if I had plans to expand and make this a larger thing, this is simply a college project in which before all we knew was how to make a simply joke API that returned one of 10 jokes, though I will keep it in my mind for the future

Comment: `/api/category/platform` and `/api/platform/price` would seem to be ambiguous, unless there is a pattern that differentiates the values that make up "category", "platform" and "price"?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and I was able to use something along the lines of

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ project3/api/index.php?category=$1&filter=$2 [L]
```

Comment: It's difficult to see how this relates to the examples in your question? Is this `.htaccess` file in the `/api/category` subdirectory?

Answer (score -1):

You can use smthing like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?category$ $1category/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this makes no attempt to answer the question. (?)